# How to delay startactivity() in android. So that volleys data can be used

Tags: android

I have a code in my android project which retrieves data using volley. I have an onclick item. What I want is, when I click the item:

1) The volley should get the data from API and after that
2) the startactivity() line executes.

But what is happening is that the startactivity() executes before volley completes.

My question is: what can be done to delay startactivity() so that volley gets the data first?

Here is my code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
       final String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);

       String url1 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid="+placeids.get(position)+"&key="+browserKey;

     JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq2 = new JsonObjectRequest(url1, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                            String latitude = response.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
                            String longitude = response.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
                            editor2.putString("udupitown_endingpointlat_1", latitude);
                            editor2.putString("udupitown_endingpointlon_1", longitude);
                            editor2.putString("udupitown_endingpointplacename_1", str);

                            editor2.commit();

                    }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jsonObjReq2, "jreq2");*/


        Intent m = new Intent(view.getContext(), VolleyMapviewerinside.class );
        startActivity(m);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> volley to get the data from api and after that  startactivity() line
>   executes.

Then instead of calling `startActivity` just before adding request to `addToReqQueue`, start Activity inside  `onResponse` method `Response.Listener` :

```
   @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        // 1. save data in SharedPreferences
        // call startActivity for starting VolleyMapviewerinside Activity
      }
```

Comment: but it asks to declare view as final. Is it good or bad to do that.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: not issue you can declare it as `final`

Comment: thank you. i was thinking the problem is with asynchronous